# Stopping default behavior of events in Swing

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, event-handling

I have the following bit of code in a method called by clicking the send button, or pressing enter in the message text field in a piece of code.

```
// In class ChatWindow
private void messageTextAreaKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) { // Event handler created by Netbeans GUI designer to call this method.           
    if(evt.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        sendMessage();
    }
}   
public void sendMessage() {
    String currentMessage = messageTextArea.getText();
    addMessage("You", currentMessage);
    app.sendMessage(currentMessage, 1);
    messageTextArea.setText("");
}
```

The last bit of code blanks the text area. However, after a message is sent by pressing the enter button, rather than being empty, the text box contains a newline.

My guess is that after my event handler runs, THEN the newline character is being added. How to I stop the newline being added?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try adding `evt.consume()` after your call to `sendMessage()`

```
private void messageTextAreaKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) { 
 if(evt.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
    sendMessage();
    evt.consume();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The default `Action` for the Enter key in a `JTextArea` is to insert a new line as you have seen. So the solution is to replace the default `Action` with a custom `Action`. The benefit of this approach is that this `Action` can also be used by the `JButton` (or `JMenuItem` etc.). An `Action` is basically the same as an `ActionListener`, all you need to do is implement the `actionPerformed()` method.

Read up on [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) to see how this is done. All Swing components use Key Bindings.

Comment: Being new to the forum as I understand it, the -2 indicates a couple of people believe the answer is wrong or missleading. Did I get the negative because I didn't explain what an Action is or for some other reason?

Also, should I be receiving automatic emails whenever a new solution/comment is added to the posting?

Comment: Seems like many people don't really help a new comer to the forums, but thankx to you, as you did helped me many a times in understanding my mistakes and pointing me in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 2):

as camickr said, 
   you should bind action to enter key;

```
Action sendAction = new AbstractAction("Send"){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
       // do your stuff here
    }
};

textarea.registerKeyboardAction(sendAction, 
       KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
sendButton.setAction(sendAction);
```

if you are more interesed, I implemented Autoindent feature for textarea, using this technique:
[here](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/autoindent_for_jtextarea)

Comment: -1 for spreading dated api (registerKeyboardAction is outdated since at least jdk 1.3, wayy before 2009 ;-)