# Add FocusListener on a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtextfield

I have a textfield in which i have to validate an Email.My problem is that i want to move the focus from the textfield only when the email is valid.I am using now a FocusAdapter.
Can someone please give me some other idea?

Comment: I'd hate to have to work with a program that behaves that way.  E.G. I'm sitting in front of a screen with 30 fields, and know the values of 29 of them, but the 30th is the email address that I need to get from my co-worker who has popped outside for a smoke.  Why limit me from entering the details of the 29 fields I know?  *"..give me some other idea?"*  Validate all the fields when the operator ***attempts to save the information.***  If there are fields that need fixing, pop a modal dialog explaining the data needed & drop them back into the form, with field focused.

Answer (score 3):

See `javax.swing.InputVerifier` and `JComponent.setInputVerifier()`
But don't forget the suggestion from Andrew. Your workflow isn't user friendly.

It was already described here: [Java - making a textbox not lose focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997988/java-making-a-textbox-not-lose-focus)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email)
{
   boolean result=true;
   try
   {
      InternetAddress emailAddr=new InternetAddress(email);
      emailAddr.validate();
   } catch(AddressException ex)
   {
      result=false;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: I have validated the Email.My problem is: when i type in some not valid email in the TextField and i move the mouse on another Component ,I need the mouse not to be able to do that,but to stay on the same Textfield until the email is valid.

Answer (score 0):

In next example you cant move to another field if validation failed, done with help of `requestFocusInWindow()` method. Try it, I think it helps you:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private JTextField f;
    private JTextField f2;
    private JTextField f3;

    public Frame() {
        f = new JTextField(5);
        f2 = new JTextField(5);
        f3 = new JTextField(5);
        f.addFocusListener(getFocusListener());
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,5,5));
        getContentPane().add(f);
        getContentPane().add(f2);
        getContentPane().add(f3);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private FocusListener getFocusListener() {
        return new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                super.focusLost(arg0);
                if(!validateEmail()){
                    f.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private boolean validateEmail() {
        return f.getText().length()<3;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Frame();

    }

}
```

Read more about [requestFocusInWindow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29) and [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)