# need to handle JTable's rows using arrow keys from the keyboard

Tags: java, swing, jtable, arrow-keys

I have to shift the cells up/down depending upon the up/down arrow key pressed from the keyboard. I am adding a `KeyListener` (in fact `KeyAdapter`) on the `JTable` to achieve it using the `keyPressed()` method. Now what's happening is that when I am pressing the alphanumeric keys, then I am able to get the selected row using `table.getSelectedRow()`, but when I am pressing the arrow keys its giving me "-1" always. That means no row is shown selected. I also tried to set the focus on table but it did not work. The code I am usin is as follows:

```
private void settingKeys() {
    controller.getStandardActionDetailsTableEquates().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            System.out.println("key pressed!!");
            controller.getStandardActionDetailsTableEquates().setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
            int selectedRow = controller.getStandardActionDetailsTableEquates().getSelectedRow();
            System.out.println("selectedRow : " + selectedRow);

            controller.getStandardActionDetailsTableEquates().requestFocusInWindow();

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                System.out.println("up arrow key pressed");

                Component editor = controller.getStandardActionDetailsTableEquates().getEditorComponent();
                editor.requestFocusInWindow();
                System.out.println("cursor : " + controller.getStandardActionDetailsTableEquates().getCursor());
                System.out.println("value : " + controller.getStandardActionDetailsTableEquates().getSelectedRow());

            } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                System.out.println("down arrow key pressed");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

I even tried to get the cursor position, but could not get it. Also, the editor found did not worked (shown in code). The "selected row" and "value" values are pining as "-1".

Please provide solution to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a `KeyListener`; use [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). `JTable` has the following default bindings in the `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` input map:

- `VK_UP` has the key `"Table.selectPreviousRow"`
- `VK_DOWN` has the key `"Table.selectNextRow"`.

You can [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto) the bindings with [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) instances that update your `TableModel` as desired. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10015234/230513) may guide you. A complete listing can be obtained using the key binding utility cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070551/230513). Implementations may be found in the table's UI delegate, [`BasicTableUI`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTableUI.java), et al. The [`EditorKit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/EditorKit.html) actions, examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20%5Bswing%5D%20EditorKit), are also worth a look. Alternatively, consider a custom `Comparator` in your `RowSorter`, as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).